# Logging Exceptions to Slack in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, slack

I have got a python script that checks if a web-page contains information or if it's empty. I want to make an application that runs this script, and tell me, preferably on slack, whether it worked or not. And I want this to happen every hour. I believe I can do this by using Application Insight with Azure, but I have not found an easy way to do this.

I'm entirely new to azure so any help would be appreciated, even simply links to other pages.

**Edit 1**

Instead of using python I instead want to try and log the exceptions I find in App insight to slack. I find these exceptions by going to app insight, then "Failures" and then "drill into operations"
[Failures in App insight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv285.png)

[These Exceptions I want to log to Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWprQ.png)

Comment: I'm not very clear about this question. what do you mean "checks if a web-page contains information or if it's empty."?

Comment: and how do you believe this can be done via application insights? please explain this a little more. Thanks:).

Comment: I now know a bit more about Azure, and I have figured out that someone alse have set up a place called Failures inside App Insight (This might be default). By going here I can press "Drill into operations", and after a few more clicks I end up with a row of "Exceptions". These Exceptions are what I want to log to Slack.  I Will add a picture to my original post

Comment: You want to log the exceptions which are in application insights, to slack?

Comment: That's right, so I don't have to enter Azure all the time, just to see if anything has failed

Comment: You can consider using [Azure Application Insights REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart). Please take a look and let me know if you have more questions:).

Comment: Thx for the help :) By looking at the page you sent and searching around for more info about Rest API's I found an app called CloudBot which did exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately it's 10p/m, so I'll see if we can use that. Thx for all the help regardless :)

Comment: Ok. And if you have issues about this rest api, please let me know:).